# Convertir LPWSTR a string

Tags: c++

Como podría convertir un `LPWSTR(Long Pointer Wide String)` a string. Tengo entendido que un LPWSTR es un puntero largo a una string constante. Pero hay alguna manera sencilla de convertir un LPWSTR ej:

```
LPWSTR a = L"check";
```

A string:

```
string b = // la conversión
```

Como podría hacerlo ya que se puede iterando y muchas maneras pero sigo teniendo dificultades.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de la macro `CW2A`. Un ejemplo:

```
#include "atlstr.h"

LPWSTR a = L"check";
std::string b = CW2A(a);
```

Más información en la [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

Usa un [`std::wstring`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
LPWSTR a = L"check";
std::wstring b = a;
```

---

#### Explicación.

> ¿Hay alguna manera sencilla de convertir un `LPWSTR` en un `string`?

No la hay. Son tipos incompatibles. El primero es un puntero apuntando a una zona de memoria que contiene una serie de caracteres mientras que el segundo es una clase que gestiona internamente un búfer de memoria dinámica que contiene caracteres pero ofrece además operaciones de consulta y modificación de dicho búfer.

Por poner una analogía: sería como intentar convertir un [transistor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor) en una radio; si bien es cierto que las radios contienen transistores, una radio es mucho más que una colección de transistores de la misma manera que un `string` es mucho más que una colección de caracteres.

Pero por suerte se puede **construir** un `string` usando los datos apuntados por un `LPWSTR`; en la práctica no habrás transformado el `LPWSTR` en `string` si no que tendrás dos datos diferentes pero con el mismo contenido.

#### Construir un `string` a partir de un `LPWSTR`.

Has señalado que `LPWSTR` es...

> Tengo entendido que un `LPWSTR` es un puntero largo a una `string` constante.

Pero esto no es del todo cierto. Para empezar no es puntero a una cadena constante (ese es el [`LPCWTSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#LPCWSTR), date cuenta que contiene una `C` para indicar que es constante). Según la documentación de Microsoft [`LPWSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#LPWSTR) es un alias de puntero a [`WCHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#WCHAR) que a su vez es un alias del tipo básico [`wchar_t`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#character_types):

```
typedef wchar_t WCHAR;
typedef WCHAR *LPWSTR;
```

Así que en el fondo, un `LPWSTR` es simplemente `wchar_t *` y la [librería de plantillas estándar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) tiene una clase [`string`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) que gestiona datos de ese tipo y en consecuencia es construible con ellos.

La clase plantilla `std::basic_string` puede gestionar cadenas de caracteres de diferentes anchos y codificaciones según cómo se configure:

- `std::basic_string<char>` para caracteres normales, tiene el alias `std::string`.
- `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` para caracteres anchos, tiene el alias `std::wstring`.
- `std::basic_string<char16_t>` para caracteres [UTF-16](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), tiene el alias `std::u16string`.
- `std::basic_string<char32_t>` para caracteres [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32), tiene el alias `std::u32string`.

Sabiendo esto, podemos construir un `string` a partir de un `LPWSTR` de la siguiente manera:

```
LPWSTR a = L"check";
std::wstring b = a;
```